# Can't obtain database connection within 5 seconds - Sidekiq workers, Unicorn, Redis ToGo on Heroku

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, sidekiq, redistogo

I've a bunch background tasks (Sidekiq workers) that update database, and I keep getting this failing thread exception.

```
Heroku Log: WARN: could not obtain a database connection within 5.000 seconds (waited 5.001 seconds)
```

- Heroku
- Heroku Postgres :: Olive - 20 connections limit.
- Redis ToGo - 10 connections limit.
- Sidekiq - 2 connections.

Each client request create ~50 threads - finally ~20 threads trying to update db.
Now I know this is too much threads trying to make connection (updating Active:Record..).
I don't mind them to wait in try again until success.

**-config/unicorn.rb**

```
worker_processes Integer(ENV["WEB_CONCURRENCY"] || 3)
timeout 30
preload_app true

before_fork do |server, worker|
  Signal.trap 'TERM' do
    puts 'Unicorn master intercepting TERM and sending myself QUIT instead'
    Process.kill 'QUIT', Process.pid
  end

  if defined?(ActiveRecord::Base)
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
  end
end

after_fork do |server, worker|
  Signal.trap 'TERM' do
    puts 'Unicorn worker intercepting TERM and doing nothing. Wait for master to send QUIT'
  end

  if defined?(ActiveRecord::Base)
      config = ActiveRecord::Base.configurations[Rails.env] ||
          Rails.application.config.database_configuration[Rails.env]
      config['pool']            =   ENV['DB_POOL'] || 2
      config['reaping_frequency'] = ENV['DB_REAP_FREQ'] || 10 # seconds
      ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(config)
  end
end
```

**-config/initializers/sidekiq.rb**

```
require 'sidekiq'
  Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
    if(database_url = ENV['DATABASE_URL'])
        p pool_size = Sidekiq.options[:concurrency] + 2
        p ENV['DATABASE_URL'] = "#{database_url}?pool=#{pool_size}"
        ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
    end
end
```

**--condig/sidekiq.yml**

```
:concurrency: 2
```

Thanks a lot for all the help,
Eldar